# Makefile C++(Linux)

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Добрый день возникла проблема с написание `Makefile`... Суть ее такова, что когда помещаю все в одну зависимость, то тогда все работает исправно, но когда начинаю разделять, то получаю разные ошибки(то ошибки линковки библиотек, то не нахождения методов и классов). Проект состоит из 5 файлов

- main.cpp
- PDfDocument.h
- PDfDocument.cpp
- XMLWriter.h
- XMLWriter.cpp.

В `main.cpp` подключаются `PDFDocument` и `XMLWriter`, `XMLWriter` в свою очередь подключает `PDfDocument`. Также есть библиотека `libpodofo` и `lintinyxml`(она представлена в виде исходников). Вот собственно сам `makefile`:

```
CC = g++
CFlAGS = -c -Wall
LIBS =-lpodofo
OBJ= main.o PDFDocument.o tinyxml.o XMLWriter.o
EXE = -o PDFParser

all: main.o PDFDocument.o XMLWriter.o
    $(CC) $(EXE) $(OBJ) $(LIBS)

main.o: PDFDocument.h XMLWriter.h main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp $(LIBS)

PDFDocument.o: PDFDocument.cpp PDFDocument.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) PDFDocument.cpp

XMLWriter.o: PDFDocument.h XMLWriter.h XMLWriter.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) XMLWriter.cpp
```

Надеюсь, что кто-нибудь подскажет где проблема или в какую сторону рыть для ее решения... Вот неполный список ошибок, здесь собствевнно не получается прилинковать библиотеку и `main` не видит конструктора класса из `XMLWriter`

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `XMLWriter::XMLWriter()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to `XMLWriter::write(PDFDocument&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x19d): undefined reference to `XMLWriter::~XMLWriter()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x27b): undefined reference to `XMLWriter::~XMLWriter()'
/tmp/ccKo7fq3.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x394): undefined reference to `PoDoFo::PdfRect::PdfRect(double, double, double, double)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3ce): undefined reference to `PoDoFo::PdfFontMetricsBase14::PdfFontMetricsBase14(char const*, PoDoFo::PODOFO_CharData const*, bool, short, short, unsigned short, unsigned short, PoDoFo::PdfRect const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x41e): undefined reference to `PoDoFo::PdfRect::PdfRect(double, double, double, double)'
```

Comment: Какие конкретно ошибки при компиляции через этот Makefile возникают?

Comment: Добавил ошибки в вопрос

Comment: Уж элементарные опечатки в тексте можно было бы найти и без "помощи клуба".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `CFlAGS` в начале файла использована маленькая `l`. В результате `CFLAGS` не выставлено, компиляция `main.cpp` идет без флага `-c` и падает из-за ошибок линковки.